# What's the Hukm of raising index finger in Tashahhud in Salah according to shiism?

Tags: salat, sunnah, shiism

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Ashraful Anbiya Sayyidina Muhammad wa 'ala 'Alihi Muhammad.

---

I want to know if my Shia brothers raise their index finger in Tashahhud in Salah?

If **"YES"** then what is their evidence?

If **"NO"** then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

raise their index finger in Tashahhud in Salah is the practical prayer that Sunni people do this while Shiites do not do this.
Sunni traditions argued that the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) in the prayer, but in the justification and purpose of it and also in quality It is also different. But this is not logged in the Shi'a commands. The Shiite does not reject this action and does not know well.

http://www.makarem.ir/main.aspx?typeinfo=21&lid=0&catid=45581&mid=267155